# Failed asserting two arrays are equal but shows that the arrays are the same with no difference?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to pass a test that involves running a query that returns a series of logins to test whether two arrays are equal in the test.

In the past I have tried changing the format of the query to make the test pass as well as editing the arrays and eventually it equalled the two arrays. Unfortunately the test still doesn't pass.

The function that performs the query to get a series of dates of logins:

```
public function getLogins(): array
{
  return $this->createQuery()
    ->select('date AS datetime, COUNT(id) as total')
    ->orderBy('datetime', 'DESC')->groupBy('datetime')
    ->where('date >= -24 hours')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

This is the method in the test class:

```
public function testGetLogins()
{
  $dateLogins = $this->repository->getLogins();

  $this->assertCount(4, $dateLogins, "Four instances");
  $this->assertEquals([
        ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -3 minutes"), "total" => "1"],
        ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -7 days"), "total" => "1"],
        ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -1 year"), "total" => "1"],
        ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -600 days"), "total" => "1"]
    ], $logins, "The login instances returned match the expected times");
}
```

I'm expecting the test to pass but instead it is displaying this:

[Test Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuPFU.png)

The expected and actual arrays are both equal so I'm unsure as to what is causing the test to fail.

Comment: `new \DateTime` will create an object not a string that is returned from the db. Probably need `->format(...)`.  However the dates won't be equal as `"now -3 minutes"` will change every minute. And you don't define `$logins` anywhere, maybe `$dateLogins`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\DateTime` format contains information about seconds as well. `new \DateTime("now -3 minutes")` will return `now` minus `3 minutes` but exact amount of `seconds`, which will be always different, depending on the time when you did launch the test. Apparently you want to compare dates till minutes, so you have to format your dates before comparsion, therefore you have to compare each set separately:

```
$expectedValues = [
    ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -3 minutes"), "total" => "1"],
    ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -7 days"), "total" => "1"],
    ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -1 year"), "total" => "1"],
    ["datetime" => new \DateTime("now -600 days"), "total" => "1"]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($expectedValues); ++$i) {
    $actualDate = (new \DateTime($logins[$i]['datetime']))->format('Y-m-d  H:i');
    $expectedDate = ($expectedValues[$i]['datetime'])->format('Y-m-d  H:i');
    $this->assertEquals($expectedDate, $actualDate);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedValues[$i]['total'], $logins[$i]['total']);
}
```